# How to check if all values in array are identical?

Tags: php, arrays

In PHP how can I quickly tell if all values in array are identical?

Comment: Also, a lot of these are googleable (like the current one) so there is no real need to post it as a question on stackoverflow

Comment: i disagree. the more data the better, even if the question exists already. it may not be "googleable" using the search term an user selects based on the way the user phrased the question. stackoverflow + google allow programmers to learn new techniques and get work done faster and more efficiently.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can use the test:

```
count(array_unique($arr)) == 1;
```

Alternatively you can use the test:

```
$arr === array_fill(0,count($arr),$arr[0]);
```

Comment: `array_unique` doesn't actually modify the original array.  Please take a look at the PHP Manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

Comment: `count(array_unique($arr)) == 1;` was the most helpful code.

Answer (score 14):

```
$results = array_unique($myArray);
if(count($results) == 1){
   // $myArray is all duplicates
}
```

Comment: Although this is a valid answer, I would also note that `array_unique` *removes* the duplicates, so this approach works if he does not need the array with all it's values.

Comment: It doesn't modify the original array (`$myArray`, in this case), rather it returns an array with duplicates removed.

Comment: Or, you can create a new variable with the array in it, and leave the original array alone.

Comment: @Anthony this function doesn't affect the original array.  So $myArray will stay the same.

Answer (score 3):

You could also use this check:

```
count(array_count_values($arr)) == 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$myArray = array('1','1','1');
$results = array_unique($myArray);
if(count($results) == 1)
{
    echo"all value is duplicates";
}
else
{
    echo"all value is not duplicates";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Do a test run and see if all results are the same:

```
foreach ($array as $newarray){
    echo $newarray. '';
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can check for `count(array_intersect($arr1, $arr2)) == 0`