# How can I find uniqueness in an array (php)

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have two possible configurations of an array in php like the following:

```
$array = array(
    "0" => "137",
    "1" => "137",
    "2" => "137",
    "3" => "137",
    "4" => "137"
);
```

and

```
$array = array(
    "0" => "137",
    "1" => "200",
    "2" => "31",
    "3" => "19",
    "4" => "400"
);
```

I am not trying to compare the arrays to each other.

It does not matter that the specific numbers are "137" or any other number for that matter, what I need to know is how to programatically determine that the first array is "true" because all of its values are the same. The second array is "false" because they are different. The second one could have any random set in it as well, including a bunch of the same number, and one different one.

I don't care really about what number is different, only if they are all the same.  I'm researching now, but I am not sure what to look for, term-wise.

Comment: Have you looked at [`array_diff()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php)?

Comment: count(array_unique($array) == 1)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2554410/how-to-check-if-all-values-in-array-are-identical

Comment: With PHP my first stop is always the [Array Functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php) documentation. In my experience there usually an existing function that does exactly what I want :-)

Comment: Yes, i did search Galen. I mentioned I was not sure of the terms to search for. I needed to search for a unique, not a difference. Sorry to have upset you.

Comment: @Galen How do you know? Would you appreciate reading a comment like that on one of your questions? http://stackoverflow.com/faq#benice

Comment: @andyb - he edited his question and title, the original was much different.

Comment: @Galen it was not that different! Also, my comment was based the original title. Edited or original, the OP even stated `I am not sure what to look for, term-wise`. I felt it was not constructive to make a statement about the OP that you had no evidence for, that's all.

Comment: @andyb - His title contained the words "array" and "different"...  Hence why the first comment has 4 votes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
if (count(array_unique($array)) > 1) {
    // not all elements are the same
}
```

Comment: +1 too fast to understand.

Comment: +1 simple & nice answer.

Comment: Thank you. I did happen on to the same answer almost immediately after I asked the question.  I was looking for a diff but it was really a "unique" type of question.

Comment: @Car It's always worth trying to approach a problem from different angles... :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the array_unique function [php array_unique](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)

if the count of the resulting array is 1 then all values are the same.

Or it may be best to just loop through the array to until you find a value that is different, this has a worse case o(n)

EDIT: Note that count(array_unique($array)) is cleaner but less eficient, still o(n) though (allways o(n) not just worse case).